# JQuery listen multiple events, but fire only once

Tags: jquery, events

How to listen to multiple events like change and input, but fire only one at time.

Example:

- On input: fire input event without change
- On change: fire change event without input

Using this code to listen to the events, but on input it's fire twice.

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/h6sny738/2/

```js
$(document).on("change input", '.test', function(event) {
  console.log("test");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="test">
```

Comment: Why do you need both events - `change` and `input`?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb Using the same method with both input and select elements and selects not firing to input event only change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your function and attach different listeners with different targets:

```js
var myFunc = function(event) {
  console.log('test', event.type, event.target.tagName);
};

$(document)
  .on('change', 'select.test', myFunc)
  .on('input', 'input.test', myFunc);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="test">
<select class="test">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```